# MYSQL Return data from selected row and row before

Tags: mysql

I have a table (price_history) that shows the price history for a given product. I'd like to make a query that shows the current price (for the most recent date) and the price right before (for the date right before the most recent) so essentially, the old and new price. Here's an example table:

```
| historyid | productcode | optionid | price | date       |
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+
|      9635 |      254256 |        1 | 42.95 | 1286494361 |
|      9690 |      254256 |        1 | 35.00 | 1286495188 |
|      9727 |      254256 |        1 | 47.95 | 1287529777 |
|      9728 |      254256 |        1 | 40.00 | 1288902624 |
```

Here's what I'd like to get:

```
| productcode | optionid | Old price |  New Price |  Date      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|      254256 |         1|     47.95 |  40.00     | 1288902624 |
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the result I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what went wrong. `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: Are `date` values always contiguous or have gaps?

Answer (score 0):

Using the data below (formatted date appropriately):

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+
| historyid | productcode | optionid | price | validdate  |
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+
|      9660 |      254256 |        1 | 35.00 | 2013-09-14 |
|      9727 |      254256 |        1 | 47.95 | 2013-09-15 |
|      9728 |      254256 |        1 | 40.00 | 2013-09-16 |
|      9635 |      254256 |        1 | 42.95 | 2013-09-13 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

To get the latest date's price and previous day's price use this:

```
select a.*, b.price as oldprice
from testing a 
left join testing b 
    on a.validdate = adddate(b.validdate, 1) 
order by a.validdate desc
limit 0, 1;

+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| historyid | productcode | optionid | price | validdate  | oldprice |
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
|      9728 |      254256 |        1 | 40.00 | 2013-09-16 |    47.95 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If dates are not contiguous, you can do something like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85579/24)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE price_history
    (`historyid` int, `productcode` int, `optionid` int, `price` double, `date` int)
;

INSERT INTO price_history
    (`historyid`, `productcode`, `optionid`, `price`, `date`)
VALUES
    (9635, 254256, 1, 42.95, 1286494361),
    (9690, 254256, 1, 35.00, 1286495188),
    (9727, 254256, 1, 47.95, 1287529777),
    (9728, 254256, 1, 40.00, 1288902624)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ph1.productcode,
       ph1.optionid,
       max(ph2.price) AS oldprice,
       ph1.price AS newprice,
       ph1.date
FROM price_history ph1
INNER JOIN price_history ph2 ON ph1.productcode = ph2.productcode AND
                         ph1.optionid = ph2.optionid AND ph2.date  < ph1.date
GROUP BY ph1.productcode, ph1.optionid, ph1.price, ph1.date
ORDER BY ph1.date DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85579/24/0)**:

```
| PRODUCTCODE | OPTIONID | OLDPRICE | NEWPRICE |       DATE |
|-------------|----------|----------|----------|------------|
|      254256 |        1 |    47.95 |       40 | 1288902624 |
```